# finding upper bound for $P(T=0)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample of Poisson distribution with parameter one. if $T=\bar{X}(n-\bar{X})$ how can find upper bound for $P(T=0)$

Comment: Presumably $\bar X$ the average?

Answer (score 2):

We have $T=0$ iff all $X_i=0$ or $\sum_i X_i = n$.  The sum of Poisson random variables is itself Poisson; in particular, $\sum_i X_i$ has Poisson($n$) distribution.  Moreover, the aforementioned events are disjoint, so

$$
P(T=0) = P(X_1=0)^n + P(\sum X_i = n^2) = e^{-n} + e^{-n} n^{n^2} / n^2 !
$$

So you can write down the probability exactly.

Somehow I'm not sure if you really wanted $T$ defined like that though ?